# In AJAX Why "X" Stand For XML

Tags: javascript, ajax

Can Anybody have an Idea Why in AJAX "X" Stand For XML ? is it for XMLHttpRequest ?

Comment: I see it is closed, although I don't know why. The answer is not that trivial to find. Ajax is indeed named after XMLHttpRequest. That object is oddly named too, because it can be used for plain text just as well. It is named this way, because it was originally added to the MSXML library that shipped with IE 5, and it was used for a more dynamic interface for Outlook Web Access, which might have been the very first Ajax enhanced application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The person who [coined the term](http://www.adaptivepath.com/ideas/ajax-new-approach-web-applications) was using XML as the data format.